# Sublime Text 3: How to create reusable custom find and replace

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-3, dreamweaver

I am trying to see if there is a way to replicate a feature in Sublime that is available in Dreamweaver. With Dreamweaver you can create custom Commands using a javascript file for the actual command and a companion HTML file for the pop-up that appears asking if you want to run the command after selecting it from the Command menu. All of mine are files that run consecutive search and replaces, which saves me a lot of time.

I am wondering if there is a similar feature where I can create a javascript file that i can run from within Sublime to search and replace multiple things one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the RegReplace Package is what you're looking for?

More info can be found on CSS-Tricks.com here:

https://css-tricks.com/run-multiple-find-replace-commands-sublime-text/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your comment, but from reading the description on the site, this sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: That's great to hear Ferkner! I'm glad my answer helped you out. Hopefully there are some nice folks over here who would like to upvote my answer a little.